# Call to undefined method PDO::bindParam(), como resolvo?

Tags: php, mysql, orientação-a-objetos, pdo

Estou iniciando os estudos de OO e decidi dar uma olhada no PDO, só que não está funcionando. Me ajudem, por favor:

```php
<?php

class Cliente {
   private $nome;
   private $email;
   private $telefone;
   protected $cpf;
   protected $senha;
   private $pdo;


   public function __construct() {
       try{
       $this-> pdo = new PDO ("mysql:host=localhost; dbname=clientes;","root","");
       } catch (PDOException $erro){
           echo "Não Foi possivel conectar ao Banco: ".$erro->getMessage();
       } 


   }
   public function cadastrar($nome, $email, $cpf, $data_nascimento, $telefone, $endereco){
               $this-> pdo -> prepare ("select CPF from cliente where CPF = ':cpf'");
               $this-> pdo -> bindParam (':cpf', $cpf);
               $this-> pdo -> execute();

               if ($this->pdo -> rowCount() >= 1){
                   echo "Cadastro já existente.";
               } else { 
               try {
               $this->pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO clientes(nome, email, data_naschimento, telefone, endereco) 
                  values (':nome',':endereco',':email',':data_nascimento', ':telefone', ':endereco')");
                  $this->pdo -> bindParam(':nome', $nome);
                  $this->pdo -> bindParam (':endereco', $email);
                  $this->pdo -> bindParam (':email', $data_nascimento);
                  $this->pdo -> bindParam (':data_nascimento', $telefone);
                  $this->pdo -> bindParam (':telefone', $endereco);
                  $this->pdo -> execute();
                  echo "Dados cadastrados com Sucesso";
               }
               catch (PDOException $erro){
                   echo "Não foi possivel inserir os dados no banco: ".$erro->getMessage();

               }

        }


   }

   public function apagarCadastro($cpf){
           //Executa uma query que apaga os dados o banco
    try{
           $this -> pdo -> prepare("DELETE FROM CLIENTE WHERE CPF = ':cpf' ");
           $this -> pdo -> bindParam (':cpf', $cpf);
           $this -> pdo -> execute();
    } 
    catch (PDOException $erro) {
           echo "Não foi possivel apagar os dados: ". $erro->getMessage();
    }
    if ($this -> pdo -> rowcount() >=1 ){
           echo "Todos os dados foram apagados com Sucesso.";
       }
   } 
   public function atualizarNome($newNome, $oldNome){
           //Executa uma query que atualiza o nome no banco
           try {
           $this -> pdo -> prepare ("UPDATE CLIENTES SET NOME = ':nome' WHERE NOME = ':nome2'");
           $this -> pdo -> bindParam (':nome', $newNome);
           $this -> pdo -> bindParam (':nome2', $oldNome);
           } catch (PDOException $erro){
               echo "Não foi possível atualizar os dados". $erro->getMessage();
           }
   }
   public function atualizarEmail(){
       //Executa uma query que atualiza o banco
   }
   public function atualizarSenha(){
       //Executa uma query que atualiza o banco
   }
   public function exibeDados(){
       //Executa uma query que da um select no banco

   }
   public function getPdo() {



   }

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O metodo [bindParam](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdostatement.bindparam.php) pertence à classe [PDOStatement](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.pdostatement.php). O método `prepare` da classe `PDO` retorna um `PDOStatement`:

```
$stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("QUERY");
$stmt->bindParam(":param", $value);
$stmt->execute();
```

Quando usar o `prepare`, atribua seu retorno a uma variavel, e use-a para associar os parametros à query com o `bindParam`.

No seu caso, podemos mudar o seguinte trecho:

```
       try {
          $this->pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO clientes(nome, email, data_naschimento, telefone, endereco) 
          values (':nome',':endereco',':email',':data_nascimento', ':telefone', ':endereco')");
          $this->pdo -> bindParam(':nome', $nome);
          $this->pdo -> bindParam (':endereco', $email);
          $this->pdo -> bindParam (':email', $data_nascimento);
          $this->pdo -> bindParam (':data_nascimento', $telefone);
          $this->pdo -> bindParam (':telefone', $endereco);
          $this->pdo -> execute();
          echo "Dados cadastrados com Sucesso";
       }
       catch (PDOException $erro){
           echo "Não foi possivel inserir os dados no banco: ".$erro->getMessage();

       }
```

Para:

```
       try {
          $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO clientes(nome, email, data_naschimento, telefone, endereco) 
          values (':nome',':endereco',':email',':data_nascimento', ':telefone', ':endereco')");
          $stmt -> bindParam(':nome', $nome);
          $stmt -> bindParam (':endereco', $email);
          $stmt -> bindParam (':email', $data_nascimento);
          $stmt -> bindParam (':data_nascimento', $telefone);
          $stmt -> bindParam (':telefone', $endereco);
          $stmt -> execute();
          echo "Dados cadastrados com Sucesso";
       }
       catch (PDOException $erro){
           echo "Não foi possivel inserir os dados no banco: ".$erro->getMessage();

       }
```

Comment: Obrigado, assim que chegar em casa irei testar. E digo se funcionou, novamente,, obrigado pela atenção.

Comment: @TiagoSilveira Sem problemas. Se essa resposta foi realmente util, selecione-a como a resposta correta para a pergunta, assim outras pessoas que tiverem a mesma duvida que voce, possam encontrar mais facilmente a solucao. :)

Comment: Muito obrigado, resolveu meu problema. Obrigado mesmo.